# Class collection to listview items

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

What I'm trying to do is make so it selects the whole transaction when a listview item is selected so I don't have to rebuild it from each of it's string components.

I can do

```
List<Transaction> Transations = getTransations();
 foreach(Transaction T in Transactions ){
    string[] row =  {T.DatabaseIndex.ToString(), T.TimeRan.ToShortTimeString(), T.MerchantID, T.OperatorID, T.TerminalID, T.AccountNumber, T.ExpDate, T.InvoiceNumber, T.PurchaseAmount, T.AuthorizeAmount, T.AcqRefData, T.RecordNo, T.CardType, T.AuthCode, T.CaptureStatus,  T.RefNo, T.ResponseOrigin, T.DSIXReturnCode, T.CmdStatus, T.TextResponse, T.UserTraceData, T.Processor};

      var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
       listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);
}
```

But that doesn't save me any work when I try to retrieve the data when the user picks it.

Comment: ListView Items need to be constructed through its subitems or passing just one string. And if you want a Details view you need to build the columns before.

Comment: Is it compilable? Never seen the `ToString` override returns `string[]`.

Comment: You're actually right, that ToString wont work at all with a different return type. I'm on the wrong track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use the `ListViewItem` constructor with a string array for subitem data and actually view your subitems you need to set a details view and define list view columns beforehand.
[image: Q26508056-class-collection-to-listview-items]

Here is a [running mockup](http://1drv.ms/12oq8dz).